# Loop through an array in Jade

Tags: node.js, pug

I am defining an array in jade an looping through it to add additional items to a list:

```
        - var currencies = ['euro', 'usd', 'pound'];
        - each currency in currencies
          li
            a(
            href='#',
            ng-if='root.currency !== currency',
            ng-click='root.currency = currency')
              = currency
```

Here the anchor is displayed properly but the parameters are not evaluated correctly. What is the correct syntax to add then in my ng-if and ng-click statements?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
- var currencies = ['euro', 'usd', 'pound'];
- var if_flag, click_flag;
- each currency in currencies
    - if_flag = root.currency !== currency ? 'true' : 'false';
    - click_flag = root.currency === currency ? 'true' : 'false';
    li
      a(href='#', ng-if=if_flag, ng_click=click_flag
      | currency
```